# How to vectorize complicated code containing eigvalsh in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code (sorry it's not too minimal, I already tried reducing it from the original).

Basically, I have issues with performance when running the `eval_s()` method/function in which I:

1) find the 4 eigenvalues of a 4x4 hermitian matrix with `eigvalsh()`

2) sum the *reciprocals* of the eigenvalues into a variable `result`

3) and I repeat steps 1 and 2 for many matrices parameterized by `x,y,z`, storing the cumulative sum in `result`.

The number of times I repeat my calculations (finding eigenvalues and summing) in step 3 depends on a variable `ksep` in my code, and I need this number to increase in my actual code (i.e., `ksep` must *decrease*).
But the calculations in `eval_s()` have a for-loop over the `x,y,z` which I'm guessing really slows things down.
[Try `ksep=0.5` to see what I mean.]

Is there a way to vectorize the method indicated in my example code (or in general, functions that involve finding eigenvalues of parameterized matrices)?

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import itertools as it
from sympy.abc import x, y, z


class Solver:
    def __init__(self, vmat):
        self._vfunc = sp.lambdify((x, y, z),
                                  expr=vmat,
                                  modules='numpy')
        self._q_count, self._qs = None, []  # these depend on ksep!

    ################################################################
    # How to vectorize this?
    def eval_s(self, stiff):
        assert len(self._qs) == self._q_count, "Run 'populate_qs' first!"
        result = 0
        for k in self._qs:
            evs = np.linalg.eigvalsh(self._vfunc(*k))
            result += np.sum(np.divide(1., (stiff + evs)))
        return result.real - 4 * self._q_count
    ################################################################

    def populate_qs(self, ksep: float = 1.7):
        self._qs = [(kx, ky, kz) for kx, ky, kz
                    in it.product(np.arange(-3*np.pi, 3.01*np.pi, ksep),
                                  np.arange(-3*np.pi, 3.01*np.pi, ksep),
                                  np.arange(-3*np.pi, 3.01*np.pi, ksep))]
        self._q_count = len(self._qs)


def test():
    vmat = sp.Matrix([[1, sp.cos(x/4+y/4), sp.cos(x/4+z/4), sp.cos(y/4+z/4)],
                      [sp.cos(x/4+y/4), 1, sp.cos(y/4-z/4), sp.cos(x/4 - z/4)],
                      [sp.cos(x/4+z/4), sp.cos(y/4-z/4), 1, sp.cos(x/4-y/4)],
                      [sp.cos(y/4+z/4), sp.cos(x/4-z/4), sp.cos(x/4-y/4), 1]]) * 2
    solver = Solver(vmat)
    solver.populate_qs(ksep=1.7)  # <---- Performance starts to worsen (in eval_s) when ksep is reduced!
    print(solver.eval_s(0.65))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test", number=100))
```

p.s. The sympy part of the code might seem strange, but it serves a purpose in my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, and here's how:

```
def eval_s_vectorized(self, stiff):
    assert len(self._qs) == self._q_count, "Run 'populate_qs' first!"
    mats = np.stack([self._vfunc(*k) for k in self._qs], axis=0)
    evs = np.linalg.eigvalsh(mats)
    result = np.sum(np.divide(1., (stiff + evs)))
    return result.real - 4 * self._q_count
```

This still leaves the evaluation of the Sympy expression unvectorized. That part is a bit tricky to vectorize, mostly because of the `1`s in the input matrix. You can make a completely vectorized version of your code by modifying `Solver` so that it replaces scalar constants with array constants in `vmat`:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
from sympy.core.numbers import Number
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import implemented_function

xones = implemented_function('xones', lambda x: np.ones(len(x)))
lfuncs = {'xones': xones}

def vectorizemat(mat):
    ret = mat.copy()
    # get the first element of the set of symbols that mat uses
    for x in mat.free_symbols: break
    for i,j in it.product(*(range(s) for s in mat.shape)):
        if isinstance(mat[i,j], Number):
            ret[i,j] = xones(x) * mat[i,j]
    return ret

class Solver:
    def __init__(self, vmat):
        self._vfunc = sp.lambdify((x, y, z),
                                  expr=vectorizemat(vmat),
                                  modules=[lfuncs, 'numpy'])
        self._q_count, self._qs = None, []  # these depend on ksep!

    def eval_s_vectorized_completely(self, stiff):
        assert len(self._qs) == self._q_count, "Run 'populate_qs' first!"
        evs = np.linalg.eigvalsh(self._vfunc(*self._qs.T).T)
        result = np.sum(np.divide(1., (stiff + evs)))
        return result.real - 4 * self._q_count

    def populate_qs(self, ksep: float = 1.7):
        self._qs = np.array([(kx, ky, kz) for kx, ky, kz
                    in it.product(np.arange(-3*np.pi, 3.01*np.pi, ksep),
                                  np.arange(-3*np.pi, 3.01*np.pi, ksep),
                                  np.arange(-3*np.pi, 3.01*np.pi, ksep))])
        self._q_count = len(self._qs)
```

## Testing/Timings

For small `ksep` the vectorized version is about 2x faster than the original, and the completely vectorized version is about 20x faster:

```
# old version for ksep=.3
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test", number=10))
-85240.46154500882
-85240.46154500882
-85240.46154500882
-85240.46154500882
-85240.46154500882
-85240.46154500882
-85240.46154500882
-85240.46154500882
-85240.46154500882
-85240.46154500882
118.42847006605007

# vectorized version for ksep=.3
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test", number=10))
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
64.95763925800566

# completely vectorized version for ksep=.3
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test", number=10))
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
5.648927717003971
```

The rounding error in the results from the vectorized version are a bit different from the original. This is presumably due to differences in how the sum in `result` is calculated.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the small rounding errors -- This works great, thanks! I'll wait abit longer to see if anyone else has better ideas, before I decide for accepting. Cheers!

Comment: I figured out a way to completely vectorize the code, including the evaluation of the Sympy expression. The completely vectorized version is 20x faster than your original. It's been added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

@tel has done most of the work. Here is how you can gain another 2x speedup on top of their 20x.

Do the linear algebra manually. When I tried that I was shocked how wasteful numpy is on small matrices:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit

# using eigvalsh
>>> print(timeit("test(False, 0.1)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=3))
-2301206.495955009
-2301206.495955009
-2301206.495955009
55.794611917983275
>>> print(timeit("test(False, 0.3)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=5))
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
-85240.46154498367
3.400342195003759

# by hand
>>> print(timeit("test(True, 0.1)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=3))
-2301206.495955076
-2301206.495955076
-2301206.495955076
26.67294767702697
>>> print(timeit("test(True, 0.3)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=5))
-85240.46154498379
-85240.46154498379
-85240.46154498379
-85240.46154498379
-85240.46154498379
1.5047460949863307
```

Note that 
part of the speedup is probably masked by shared code, on the linear algebra alone it seems to be more though I didn't check too keenly.

One caveat: I'm using Schur complement on a 2by2 split of the matrices to compute the diagonal elements of the inverse. This will fail if the Schur complements do not exist, i.e. if either the top left or the bottom right sub matrix is not invertible.

Here is the modified code:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
from sympy.core.numbers import Number
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import implemented_function

xones = implemented_function('xones', lambda x: np.ones(len(x)))
lfuncs = {'xones': xones}

def vectorizemat(mat):
    ret = mat.copy()
    for x in mat.free_symbols: break
    for i,j in it.product(*(range(s) for s in mat.shape)):
        if isinstance(mat[i,j], Number):
            ret[i,j] = xones(x) * mat[i,j]
    return ret

class Solver:
    def __init__(self, vmat):
        vmat = vectorizemat(vmat)
        self._vfunc = sp.lambdify((x, y, z),
                                  expr=vmat,
                                  modules=[lfuncs, 'numpy'])
        self._q_count, self._qs = None, []  # these depend on ksep!

    def eval_s_vectorized_completely(self, stiff):
        assert len(self._qs) == self._q_count, "Run 'populate_qs' first!"
        mats = self._vfunc(*self._qs.T).T
        evs = np.linalg.eigvalsh(mats)
        result = np.sum(np.divide(1., (stiff + evs)))
        return result.real - 4 * self._q_count

    def eval_s_pp(self, stiff):
        assert len(self._qs) == self._q_count, "Run 'populate_qs' first!"
        mats = self._vfunc(*self._qs.T).T
        np.einsum('...ii->...i', mats)[...] += stiff
        (A, B), (C, D) = mats.reshape(-1, 2, 2, 2, 2).transpose(1, 3, 0, 2, 4)
        res = 0
        for AA, BB, CC, DD in ((A, B, C, D), (D, C, B, A)):
            (a, b), (c, d) = DD.transpose(1, 2, 0)
            rdet = 1 / (a*d - b*b)[:, None]
            iD = DD[..., ::-1, ::-1].copy()
            iD.reshape(-1, 4)[..., 1:3] *= -rdet
            np.einsum('...ii->...i', iD)[...] *= rdet
            (Aa, Ab), (Ac, Ad) = AA.transpose(1, 2, 0)
            (Ba, Bb), (Bc, Bd) = BB.transpose(1, 2, 0)
            (Da, Db), (Dc, Dd) = iD.transpose(1, 2, 0)
            a = Aa - Ba*Ba*Da - 2*Bb*Ba*Db - Bb*Bb*Dd
            d = Ad - Bd*Bd*Dd - 2*Bc*Bd*Db - Bc*Bc*Da
            b = Ab - Ba*Bc*Da - Ba*Bd*Db - Bb*Bd*Dd - Bb*Bc*Dc
            res += ((a + d) / (a*d - b*b)).sum()
        return res - 4 * self._q_count

    def populate_qs(self, ksep: float = 1.7):
        self._qs = np.array([(kx, ky, kz) for kx, ky, kz
                    in it.product(np.arange(-3*np.pi, 3.01*np.pi, ksep),
                                  np.arange(-3*np.pi, 3.01*np.pi, ksep),
                                  np.arange(-3*np.pi, 3.01*np.pi, ksep))])
        self._q_count = len(self._qs)


def test(manual=False, ksep=0.3):
    vmat = sp.Matrix([[1, sp.cos(x/4+y/4), sp.cos(x/4+z/4), sp.cos(y/4+z/4)],
                      [sp.cos(x/4+y/4), 1, sp.cos(y/4-z/4), sp.cos(x/4 - z/4)],
                      [sp.cos(x/4+z/4), sp.cos(y/4-z/4), 1, sp.cos(x/4-y/4)],
                      [sp.cos(y/4+z/4), sp.cos(x/4-z/4), sp.cos(x/4-y/4), 1]]) * 2
    solver = Solver(vmat)
    solver.populate_qs(ksep=ksep)  # <---- Performance starts to worsen (in eval_s) when ksep is reduced!
    if manual:
        print(solver.eval_s_pp(0.65))
    else:
        print(solver.eval_s_vectorized_completely(0.65))
```

Comment: Your code is impressive as always. I do sometimes wonder what your day job must be...